# Spring Boot deploy fail - Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a spring boot application which I deploy to VPS. Everything was working fine. but from last few days I am facing error when I deploy my war file to the server. I am sure I didn't touched any configuration in pom.xml or tomcat lately. Below is the stack trace and my pom.xml.

Everything works fine in local but when I deploy war file to server, getting below error trace.

```
2020-09-15 01:11:36,091 INFO  [Catalina-utility-1] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-15 01:11:36,103 WARN  [Catalina-utility-1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
2020-09-15 01:11:36,114 INFO  [Catalina-utility-1] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener: 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-09-15 01:11:36,118 ERROR [Catalina-utility-1] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
    at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:66)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor$MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut.matches(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:251)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:288)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    ... 57 common frames omitted
15-Sep-2020 01:11:36.119 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/common-service.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1848)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/common-service]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'meterRegistryPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogMessage
        at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.java:65)
        at org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java:66)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor$MethodSecurityMetadataSourcePointcut.matches(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:251)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:288)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:320)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.log.LogMessage
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        ... 57 more
15-Sep-2020 01:11:36.120 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/common-service.war] has finished in [7,083] ms
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ec</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>common-service</name>
    <description>common-service</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.bohnman</groupId>
            <artifactId>squiggly-filter-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>common-service</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <annotationProcessorPath>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </annotationProcessorPath>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anybody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]It seems related to pom.xml

Can you try with higher spring boot version? ie  `<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>`

I'm using this release

Comment: I tried with 2.1.7 and 2.2.2 as well. But same issue

Comment: Also, I didnt modified my pom.xml from long time. It was working fine till few days ago. Not sure what went wrong

Comment: can u try to overwrite this dependency?
spring-core
5.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: If u sure that not related to pom.xml, you can remove .m2 then let maven update dependencies again. It's just a trick cuz may have multiple `LogMessage` classes in your env

Comment: Thanks @Toàn Nguyễn Hải > it worked. I cleared all dependency files and let maven re-download them. it worked.